# My autoloader should trigger a "throw new Exception" but ends with "Fatal error"

Tags: php, exception, autoload

My autoloader should trigger a "throw new Exception" but ends with **"Fatal error: Class 'App\Asdfg' not found [...]"**

My autoload receives the class name and namespace matches the directory file

```
Class Autoloader: 
$position = strpos($class, '\\'); 
System::load(substr($class, 0, $position), substr($class, $position + 1)); 

Class System
function load($dir, $file) {
  if (! isset(system::$dirs[$dir])) 
  throw new Exception($dir); 

  include system::$dirs[$dir].'\\'.$file; 
}
```

When I try to instantiate a class that does not exist should I get an Exception, but it is not working ...

> new \ App \ asdfg;
>
> Fatal error: Class 'App \ asdfg' not found [...]

where possible error'm making?

Comment: `class classname { ...... }`

Comment: where are the other comments that were here?

Comment: I don't see any test to see if the file exists or not before including it? You simply try including it, which gives a fatal error if it doesn't exist

Comment: I'm not checking if the file just testing the path with: `if (! isset(system::$dirs[$dir]))`

Comment: So you will get a Fatal error if the file isn't there.... use a file_exists test first, and throw an exception if false